# Extracting values using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file as

```
Time = 0

Reading fields:
    volScalarField: grad(T)y

Executing functionObjects
surfaceFieldValue patchIntegrate(name=down,grad(T)y) write:
    total faces   = 4000
    total area    = 5.286456431623655e-06

    areaIntegrate(down) of grad(T)y = -0.3799414476287353
Space-averaged Nusselt lambda = 5.34607670341618

Time = 0.45

Reading fields:
    volScalarField: grad(T)y

Executing functionObjects
surfaceFieldValue patchIntegrate(name=down,grad(T)y) write:
    areaIntegrate(down) of grad(T)y = -0.6680860499604798
Space-averaged Nusselt lambda = 5.34607670341618
```

Then I want to extract time and different variables from it as a table. For example when I enter

```
grep -e '^Time =' -e '^Space-averaged Nusselt lambda =' file | awk -F'=' '/Time =/ {t=$NF} /Space-averaged Nusselt lambda*/ {print t"   "$NF}' >> Nusselt.dat # Print results
```

the results will be as in Nusselt.dat file

```
 0   5.34607670341618
 0.45    5.34607670341618
```

Now I want to have extract the "areaIntegrate(down) of grad(T)y". Like previous command here I will use the command as

```
grep -e '^Time =' -e '^    areaIntegrate(down) of grad(T)y =' log.patchIntegrate | awk -F'=' '/Time =/ {t=$NF} /areaIntegrate(down) of grad(T)y*/ {print t" "$NF}' >> patchIntegrate.dat # Print results
```

My expected results is patchIntegrate.dat with content as

```
 0   -0.3799414476287353
 0.45    -0.6680860499604798
```

But I do not get any result. Now I am wondering what the problem is with this last command?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please do post sample of your expected output more clearly in your question, thank you.

Comment: The brackets/parentheses in the regex `//` have to be escaped.

Comment: You included too many spaces or the spaces are actually tabs. Remove the hat (`^`) and spaces, then it works here

Comment: btw, you don't need awk for this, e.g. with `cut` and `paste`: `grep ... | cut -d= -f2 | paste - - -`. Assuming your values come in triplets

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I edited the question and right now it has the expected result, THanks

Comment: @Thor regarding your first comment, do you mean using a command like 

grep -e '^Time =' -e 'areaIntegrate(down) of grad(T)y =' log.patchIntegrate | awk -F'=' '/Time =/ {t=$NF} /areaIntegrate(down) of grad(T)y*/ {print t" "$NF}' >> patchIntegrate.dat # Print results

I did that I still no result, And thanks for your time

Comment: @AndreWildberg Do yo mean 

grep -e '^Time =' -e '^    areaIntegrate\(down\) of grad\(T\)y =' log.patchIntegrate | awk -F'=' '/Time =/ {t=$NF} /areaIntegrate\(down\) of grad\(T\)y*/ {print t" "$NF}' >> patchIntegrate.dat # Print results

I tried this, and still no answer, and thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk -F'=' '
/^Time/{
  t=$NF
  next
}
/([[:space:]]+|^)areaIntegrate\(down\) of grad\(T\)y[[:space:]]+/ && t!=""{
   print t,$NF
  t=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

- First of all setting field separator as `=` for all the line of Input_file in `awk` program here.
- Then in main block of the program checking condition if line starts from `Time` then setting variable `t` to last field(`$NF`).
- Then using `next` to skip all further statements from here.
- Then checking condition using regex `([[:space:]]+|^)areaIntegrate\(down\) of grad\(T\)y[[:space:]]+`(explained below, [Online Demo for used regex](https://regex101.com/r/S7FDhh/1)) AND variable `t` is NOT NULL then do following actions:
- Print value t and `$NF`(last field of current line).
- Nullifying `t` here to avoid any false positives here.